# Java Program in Eclipse

Tags: java

How do I make a util class with a method name that is add, and returns the result by adding two numbers.This is in java but in the program eclipse.

This is what I've got:

```
public class Util { 

    public static int add(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) { 
        int first = 2; 
        int second =3; 
        int second - Util.add(int, int) 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What are the errors? -- what is the question?

Comment: It's good that you've posted code, but it's not what you want, and you will want to start over. Have you reviewed examples of similar programs in your text book? I would start there, emulate what they do with parameters (hint -- you've got to use your parameters within the method), and then try to re-write this.

Comment: This is the question: How do I make a util class with a method name that is add, and returns the result by adding two numbers?

Comment: Try looking at some examples online. You can check here: http://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Functions

Comment: That's not a valid stackoverflow question as it's more like a restatement of an assignment. Instead we usually recommend that you state clearly what you don't understand, but since this involves the most basic rudiments of java, the best thing for you to do is as I suggested above, re-read (or read) your text book. You must learn the basics yourself, since our showing you how to do this won't help you in the long run. good luck.

Comment: well, do you know how to add two numbers in Java? If you know that, then you can encapsulate that code inside your function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the best solution is to study and try to understand Java basics and not to ask for code on this site.

Comment: Well, if I would tell you two numbers and ask you to add them, would you ignore my numbers and use your own instead? Try to think what you would do if you would have the same job to do like your method? If you know that, then write your program to do the same. This helps sometimes, especially for such small task abd if you're new.

Comment: Is this right:public class Util { 

 public static int add(int first, int second) { 
 return first + second; 
 } 
  

 int result = Util.add(2 , 2); 
}

Comment: @TrishGoal Yes it is. See, wasn't that hard :).

Answer (score 2):

As a Java novice myself, this is the first Stack Overflow question I've actually been capable of answering.  I agree with other commenters that this is probably better answered by reviewing a basic Java textbook of some kind, but here you go:

```
    public class Util {
        public static int add(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) { 
            return firstNumber + secondNumber; 
        }  
    }
```

Comment: @Downvoter if you have something that bothers you with this answer, then you should tell Paul B that, so he can improve his answer.